# Unity game Socket connection bug on EC2

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, socket.io

I am developinng multiplayer Unity3d game using socket.io and it works well on localhost, heroku.
But it seems not to work after deploying the backend code on AWS EC2.

**Here is unity Code.**

```
public void ConnectWithSocketServer()
    {
        if (socket == null)
        {
            socket = SocketIo.establishSocketConnection(ws://domain.com/);
            socket.connect();
            if (!isListerCreated)
            {
                Debug.Log("<===== Creating Socket Listener =====>");
                ListenSocket();
            }
            isListerCreated = true;
        }
    }
```

**This is app.js server code.**

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true,  
        allowedHeaders: ["content-type"],
    },
  transports: ['websocket'],
  secure: true,
  allowUpgrades: false,
  pingTimeout: 600000,
  // pingInterval: 300000
});


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up and running on port ' + (process.env.PORT || 5000));
});

const socketEvemts = require('./socketEvents');
socketEvemts(io);
```

**This is socketEvents.js code**

```
exports = module.exports = function(io) {
  var players = {};
  //Set Listener
  io.on('connection', (socket)=> {

    console.log('a user has connected');

    socket.on("ping", (data) => {
      console.log("Pong Time ===>", data);

      socket.emit("pong", "result");
    })
    ....
  });
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

For socket.io, Nothing to display when I used console.log .
But API works well.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what not working means? If there's no error messages at all could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Jay.
Yes. As you can see the code, "a user has connected" should be displayed on console when user tries to connect socket, but nothing to happen :(

Comment: Are you sure it’s listening on an ip other than 127.0.0.1

Comment: Hi, @BugFinder, thanks for your reply.
As I said and as you can see screenshot, API works well on ec2 and only socket doesn't work. 
api is https ://example.com
socket ws is ws://example.com
I also tried with wss, but it doesn't work as well